# htaccess RewriteRule issues - something wrong with my syntax?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want my sites to redirect following this protocol :

```
/weddings/ >> ?q=weddings
/editorial/one/ >> ?q=editorial&z=one
```

so I made the following rewrite rule : 
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/$? /?z=$1&q=$2 [nocase]

which when implemented totally screwed everything up.

what simple thing am i doing wrong!?

my current .htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex index.html.var index.htm index.html index.shtml index.xhtml index.wml          index.perl index.pl index.plx index.ppl index.cgi index.jsp index.js index.jp index.php4 index.php3 index.php index.phtml default.htm default.html home.htm index.php5 Default.html Default.htm home.html

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^elijahhoffman\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.elijahhoffman\.com$
RewriteRule ^journal$ "http\:\/\/elijahj\.tumblr\.com\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^elijahhoffman\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.elijahhoffman\.com$
RewriteRule ^blog\/?$ "http\:\/\/elijahj\.tumblr\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Screwed everything up  how? What does it do instead of what it should do?

Comment: And what resides at `/`? Something like an `index.php`?

Comment: yes, but it never shows in the url - i think the initial rewrite for my site redirects everything towards index.*** --- it made the pages unavailable when used. do you see any error in my rule?

Comment: Initial rewrite? If you have other rewrites, you need to post them all here, as they are all relevant.

Comment: That's a start, but still it is not clear - what is receiving `?q=$1&z=$2` ? You must be sending those to something like `index.php` - what is it?

Comment: Ok then I thought so. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent a rewrite loop, you'll need to guard against real files or directories (such as your index) being rewritten.  Append a `[L]` flag to stop on the first match.

```
RewriteEngine On

# First do your journal/blog rewrites
# Only need one condition to match both domains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?elijahhoffman\.com$
# Combine these into one rule (dots & slashes don't need escaping on the rewrite side)
RewriteRule ^(journal|blog)/?$ http://elijahj.tumblr.com/ [R=301,L]

# Then the generic one...
# If it isn't a real file or directory...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Rewrite those with only one component up to /
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?q=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Rewrite those with 2 components
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^./]+)/?$ index.php?q=$1&z=$2 [L]
```

Comment: works like a charm - the only issue i seem to be having is when something like /editorial/one is loaded the link to my index.css in the index.php file is searching in /editorial/ instead of the main directory. i suppose ill just have to use full links instead?

Comment: Yes, that's easiest. Or add another rewrite that always redirects `index.css` to `/index.css`.

Comment: will full links make it run through another dns request? just worried about load time - although with the amount of images i'm using it's probably nominal

Comment: No, the client would cache DNS accordingly. You don't need a full URL with protocol anyway, you can just specify the absolute path `/index.css` instead of `index.css`

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much mike, most thorough stack-overflow response i've ever gotten! You da bomb!

Comment: Everyone deserves thorough answers. Don't be afraid to pry for more info if you get a code-only solution without explanation.

Comment: Ah last item! I have a php script that is reading a directory for files on each page... for some reason '../galleries/' doesn't work.. neither does the full link. It's using the opendir cmd

Comment: That's a separate PHP issue, but probably solvable using something like `__DIR__ . '/../galleries'` if you had been using something like `REQUEST_URI` before the rewrite. This way, `__DIR__` is always relative to `index.php` and will always work as a filesystem path.